# Eliminar un registro enviado por XHR

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Necesito eliminar un registro con `idPago` que viene al hacer clic en un botón desde `contentDefault` en una columna de un [DataTable](https://datatables.net/).

Los datos que envío desde JavaScript los obtengo con dos funciones que muestro a continuación:

```
function getDataFromButton(button) {
    row = $(button).parents("tr");
    data = $("#payments_table").DataTable().row(row).data()
    return data; // Mi data sería toda la fila de información de ese registro
}

function eliminar(button){
    data = getDataFromButton(button); // Mi data sería data.idPago ej "2553"
    $.ajax({
        url: "eliminar_pago.php",
        data:data, 
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        if (data.estado) {
        console.log("JALA");
    } else {
        console.log("NO JALA");
    }
    }).fail(function(jqXHR) {
        console.log(jqXHR.statusText);
    });
    return false;
}
```

En mi archivo `eliminar_pago.php` tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    # INCLUDES
    include("database/database.php");
    include("models/response.php");
    # SENTENCIA PHP MYSQL
    $response = new Response();
    $pagoEliminar = $POST['idPago'];

    if(!empty($_POST['idPago'])) {
        $stmt_mysql = "DELETE FROM pagos WHERE idPago = '$pagoEliminar'";
        $t_mysql = mysqli_query($mysql_conexion_pb, $stmt_mysql);
    }

    if($t_mysql) {
        $response->estado = true;
        $response->mensajeError = "Pago eliminado";
    } else{ 
        $response->estado = false;
        $response->mensajeError = "Pago no eliminado";
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Como quien dice, ahora sí me estresé.

No doy de cómo pasar la variable `data.idPago` por `POST` para que se lea como un `$_POST['idPago']`

¿Cómo se puede realizar eso? Lo he intentando, todo se va por fallo del XHR.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir un `console.log(data);` justo antes del `$.ajax()`. Es para comprobar que contiene lo que esperas.

Comment: PD: Imagino que tu script llega al `console.log(jqXHR.statusText);`, ¿o llega al `console.log("NO JALA");`?

Comment: console.log(data); muestra la información de esa fila, idPago, quienPago, cuantoPago y si manda al console del faile el jqXHR

Answer (score 3):

Tu código debería funcionar correctamente, pero existen varias puntos en los que el código podría fallar silenciosamente.

Uno de esos puntos es que tu PHP devuelve un documento HTML que tu código jQuery no convertirá de manera automática a un dato nativo de JavaScript.

Para corregirlo debes enviar la siguiente cabecera HTTP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Por otro lado no estás enviando el posible mensaje de error al hacer la consulta SQL, obteniendo únicamente un error y no el motivo del error.

Te recomiendo que tu código sea como te muestro. En los comentarios te explico qué hago en cada momento:

```
<?php
/* Indicamos que vamos a devolver un valor JSON */
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

session_start();
# INCLUDES (no necesitas paréntesis, no son funciones)
include "database/database.php";
include "models/response.php";

# SENTENCIA PHP MYSQL
$response = new Response();

/* En caso de que nos hayan entregado un "idPago" */
if (empty($_POST['idPago']) === false) {
    /* Preparamos la consulta */
    $stmt_mysql = "DELETE FROM pagos WHERE idPago = ?";
    $p_mysql = mysqli_prepare(
        $mysql_conexion_pb,
        $stmt_mysql
    );
    /* Asignamos el valor al marcador */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($p_mysql, "s", $_POST['idPago']);
    /* En caso de error en la consulta SQL mostramos el mensaje */
    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($p_mysql) === false) {
        /* Devolvemos el error junto con el mensaje de error */
        die(json_encode([
            "estado" => false,
            "mensajeError" => "Error SQL: ". mysqli_stmt_error($p_mysql),
        ]));
    }
    /* Devolvemos un estado correcto */
    die(json_encode([
        "estado" => true,
        "mensajeError" => "Pago eliminado",
    ]));
}

/* En caso de que no nos entreguen un "idPago" también es un error */
die(json_encode([
    "estado" => false,
    "mensajeError" => "Se alcanzó el final del script inesperadamente",
]));

/* No es necesario ni recomendable cerrar PHP en scripts con solo codigo */
```

PD: Tu código puede sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). Para evitarlo he usado consultas preparadas en el código que te proporciono.

Comment: No funciona la manera como lo pusiste, se fue por la parte de "Se alcanzó el final del script inesperadamente" y no elimina, entiendo lo de SQL Inyección pero de momento es un programa sencillo, te agradezco si lo pones tambien por procedimientos.

Entonces cuando envio desde mi AJAX con data:data como lo recibo en mi eliminar_pago.php tambien con $_POST['idPago'];

Comment: Al parece eliminar_pago.php no recibe nada por eso de va por /* En caso de que no nos entreguen un "idPago" también es un error */

Comment: Gracias por avisar. Era una errata en el `if`. Ya está corregido.

Answer (score -1):

Lo resolví con PHP por procedimientos, de hecho mi código estaba bien solo era error con $POST le faltaba _ era $_POST

Comment: Primera moraleja: no uses una variable transitoria como `$pagoEliminar`. Recuerda los consejos que te puse en mi respuesta.

Comment: La tomo en cuenta pero de momento no estoy tomando en cuenta esos punto ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Deberías tomarlo en cuenta. La inyección SQL es un tema serio que debes atajar desde el principio y, sobre todo, acostumbrarte a hacer las cosas con consultas preparadas y **NUNCA** concatenar a una consulta SQL datos que no están bajo tu control (como un campo de formulario, sea enviado mediante XHR o mediante un formulario real).

Comment: No olvides aceptar las respuestas que te fueron más útiles (tanto en esta como en otras preguntas), ya que [el usuario "Comunidad" se encarga de revivir las preguntas cada cierto tiempo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215/qu%c3%a9-sucede-con-las-preguntas-que-tienen-respuestas-validas-pero-no-son-marcadas/1452), además de que las preguntas quedan _al aire_ sin respuestas aceptadas.